# Handling whitespace in GNU Make foreach

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, openscad

I want to write a generic Makefile for OpenSCAD 3D designs.

Those designs consist of a `.scad` file and a corresponding `.json` file, which contains parameter sets.

The Make file should create a folder named `output` and call OpenSCAD for each parameter set found in the `.json` file.

So far I've come up with this:

```
# Parametric OpenSCAD design file
OPENSCAD_FILE = hsw_parametric_hook.scad

# JSON file containing parameter sets
PARAMETER_SETS_FILE = hsw_parametric_hook.json

# Output directory for generated STL files
OUTPUT_DIR = output

# Function to extract parameter set names from the JSON file
get_parameter_set_names = $(shell jq -r '.parameterSets | keys[]' $(PARAMETER_SETS_FILE))

# Function to construct the STL filename for a given parameter set
stl_filename = $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(basename $(OPENSCAD_FILE))-$(1).stl

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OUTPUT_DIR) $(foreach set,$(call get_parameter_set_names),$(call stl_filename,$(set)))

$(OUTPUT_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(call stl_filename,%): $(OPENSCAD_FILE) $(PARAMETER_SETS_FILE)
    openscad -o $@ $(OPENSCAD_FILE) -p $(PARAMETER_SETS_FILE) -P '$(subst .stl,,$(subst $(subst .scad,,$(OPENSCAD_FILE))-,,$(@F)))'

clean:
    rm -f $(OUTPUT_DIR)/*.stl
```

The problem with this is, that it can't handle parameter set names containing a space character.
I guess quoting is missing or messed up somehow.

Could anyone tell me how I could fix this?

The current directory could also contain more than one set of `.scad` and `.json` files. I would like the Makefile to be able to handle this as well and ideally not have those filenames hard-coded, as they are right now.

Any suggestions?

---

Update 2024-03-29:

I've incorporated a suggestion from @JohnBollinger to add a missing dependency, though it is unrelated to the issue.

I also created a more complete example, as requested by @MadScientist:

*cylinder.scad*

```
diameter = 10;
heigh = 5;

cylinder(d=diameter, h=height);
```

*cylinder.json*

```
{
    "parameterSets": {
        "Wide cylinder": {
            "diameter": "20",
            "height": "5"
        }
    },
    "fileFormatVersion": "1"
}
```

*Makefile*

```
# Parametric OpenSCAD design file
OPENSCAD_FILE = cylinder.scad

# JSON file containing parameter sets
PARAMETER_SETS_FILE = cylinder.json

# Output directory for generated STL files
OUTPUT_DIR = output

# Function to extract parameter set names from the JSON file
get_parameter_set_names = $(shell jq -r '.parameterSets | keys[]' $(PARAMETER_SETS_FILE))

# Function to construct the STL filename for a given parameter set
stl_filename = $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(basename $(OPENSCAD_FILE))-$(1).stl

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OUTPUT_DIR) $(foreach set,$(call get_parameter_set_names),$(call stl_filename,$(set)))

$(OUTPUT_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(call stl_filename,%): $(OPENSCAD_FILE) $(PARAMETER_SETS_FILE) $(OUTPUT_DIR)
    openscad -o $@ $(OPENSCAD_FILE) -p $(PARAMETER_SETS_FILE) -P '$(subst .stl,,$(subst $(subst .scad,,$(OPENSCAD_FILE))-,,$(@F)))'

clean:
    rm -f $(OUTPUT_DIR)/*.stl
```

Running `make` now, creates the following output:

```
openscad -o output/cylinder-Wide.stl cylinder.scad -p cylinder.json -P 'Wide'
Geometries in cache: 1
Geometry cache size in bytes: 2456
CGAL Polyhedrons in cache: 0
CGAL cache size in bytes: 0
Total rendering time: 0:00:00.000
   Top level object is a 3D object:
   Facets:         18
openscad -o output/cylinder-cylinder.stl cylinder.scad -p cylinder.json -P 'cylinder'
Geometries in cache: 1
Geometry cache size in bytes: 2456
CGAL Polyhedrons in cache: 0
CGAL cache size in bytes: 0
Total rendering time: 0:00:00.000
   Top level object is a 3D object:
   Facets:         18
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided a specific example of the problem.  What is the failure you see when there is a parameter set name containing a space?

Comment: Note that you call your `get_parameter_set_names` a function, but it is not useful to define GNU `make` "functions" that do not make use of parameters.  "Calling" such a function just expands the macro (variable) , exactly as expanding it as a macro (`$(get_parameter_set_names)`) would do.

Comment: Not directly related to your issue, I think, but `$(OUTPUT_DIR)` should be a prerequisite of `$(call stl_filename,%)`, because that rule's recipe will fail if the output directory does not exist.  It is not safe to rely on the directory being a prerequisite of the default target (`all` in your case) because with a parallel build or a direct build of one of the .stl files, the output directory might not be built first.

Comment: Overall, you seem to want to write a script, not a makefile (both conceptually and literally).  It might make sense to put `make` behind such a script, but makefiles themselves don't serve well as scripts.  They were never designed to do.  They are primarily declararative, not imperative.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Thanks for the tip. Of course. I just overlooked this and will add it to my code.

Comment: @MadScientist: I cooked up a better example. I will edit my original post and add it at the bottom.

Comment: The problem is that `$(foreach set,$(call get_parameter_set_names),` is neuralgic to spaces within the result  of `get_parameter_set_names`. The best way would be to get rid of spaces in filenames. The second best is to try to work around the limitation by masking the spaces at the point of reading them in and replacing them properly. `jq` puts a line break between single outputs so it should be no problem to `$(subst  ,_,$(shell ...))`.

Comment: The short answer is, make (all variants, including GNU Make) do not support filenames containing whitespace.  If you must have filenames containing whitespace it's likely that make and makefiles are not the solution you want and you should either find a way to change your environment to avoid whitespace in filenames, or choose a different tool than `make` to handle your builds.  The longer answer is there are gross and complex ways to mimic support of whitespace, if you have no other alternatives.